# Android bundle identifier for different appstores

Tags: android, google-play

I have an `Android` app that I plan to publish on both the Google Play Store and the Xiaomi Appstore (it's a Chinese Android app store, by the way).

Do I have to make 2 versions of my app with different bundle identifiers? Or is it fine to use the same bundle identifier across different app stores?

I don't know if there are any consequences of using the same bundle identifier on different app stores so I want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess technically you could. The only implication that comes to mind is if a user comes across the case of installing both applications. The device will recognize the second installation as the same application and probably have some sort of conflict. The conflict will either mess up how updates work and/or require an uninstall/reinstall. I think it will be easier and more convenient in the long run to have different package names (bundle identifier).

Comment: Ah...That makes sense. I'll go ahead and have separate package names. Thanks!